# Hiding gallery and nav for Lightbox2 when only one image

Tags: angular, lightbox2

I have Lightbox2 by Lokesh Dhakar set up in an Angular 6.1.10 project. It is applied to just one image like so:

```
<a href="../../assets/graph.png" data-lightbox="image" >
  <img src="../../assets/graph.png" />
</a>
```

The docs (https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) state that it can be applied to single images or image sets. Even though I am applying it to a single image, the gallery navigation still appears at the bottom of the page. Obviously with just one image, I don't want the gallery navigation to appear. I just want to be able to click on the single image, and have it appear large in lightbox mode, and then close it.

Inspecting the gallery/navigation -- which gets inserted at build (ie not by me) -- it looks structured like this:

```
<lb-outerContainer>
    <lb-container>
        <lb-nav>...</lb-nav>
    </lb-container>
</lb-outContainer>
```

I can hide the display of the lb-nav elements - but it leaves a big space for the containers. If I put display:none on lb-container or lb-outerContainer it hides the gallery/nav, which is good -- but it also hides the display of the large single lightbox image when I click on it, which defeats the purpose.

Is there a way of hiding just the gallery and navigation, without compromising lightbox functionality, or is there something I have missed in configuration which would make this easier?

Comment: The previous/next navigation should not appear for single images. You can see this working on the main site: https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Is this an issue with the Angular Lightbox lib?

Comment: By the Angular lightbox lib, do you mean nxg-lightbox ? If so -- no, I'm not using that; it doesn't exist in my npm modules.  (Thank you for the comment anyway)

Comment: Its weird -- what is happening is that a div with id=lightbox is occurring twice on my page. (along with a duplicate div id=lightboxOverlay) -- the first set is where I have put it, but then a duplicate is being inserted directly after the script tags at the base of the page.

Comment: Putting "display:none" on some elements (but not others) in the css that resides at node_modules/lightbox2/dist/css/lightbox.css mostly fixes things as a workaround until something better crops up, or I figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: For the original Lightbox2 script, if you're using that, you don't need to add any of the lightbox html elements in your markup. They are appended to the bottom of the `<body>` tag by the script: https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/dev/src/js/lightbox.js#L102

Comment: On applying lightbox2 to a different project, but using the lightbox2-dev zip from the github repo rather than the lightbox2-master zip from your site -- problem seems to be resolved: single image view works as expected

Comment: As an aside (for anyone who might encounter this) -- for Angular (or at least Angular 5 or 6), referencing lightbox.js from the scripts section of angular-cli works, rather than using a <script src=''path/to/lightbox.js"></script> in your html (as prescribed in lokeshdhakar.com)

Comment: Thanks for following up with details. Glad you got it sorted.

I'll take a peek to see what discrepancies there are between `dev` and `master` at the moment.